# How to delete a file using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android

How can I delete files using Storage Access Framework in Android? I found this method in the documentation but couldn't get it working: DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(ContentResolver, Uri);

Can I delete a specific file without asking user what to delete with this?

**Edit:**

I tried getting file uri with Uri.fromFile, failed with null pointer exception.
I tried getting file uri by using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT but it asks user to select a file (i want to specify the file myself). Even like this it didn't work, giving exception and telling me delete not supported.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "couldn't get it working" means.

Comment: I tried to clarify it. I want to know if i can delete an arbitrary file in storage root by using SAF (i want to specify that file myself).

Answer (score 5):

Use the application context to call the context resolver.

`DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),uri)`

Answer (score 4):

I have got answer for your question,
If you have the URI for a document and the document's Document.COLUMN_FLAGS contains SUPPORTS_DELETE, you can delete the document. For example:

DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), uri);

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html
All the best

Comment: I did read that myself. There was no working example. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You first need writing permission for the uri in order to make changes.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        }
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE)
```

if you receive the result in the activity, you will be able to make changes to the files inside chosen directory. (Use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for single file).

if you need examples, you can find it [here](https://github.com/SomeoneAndNoone/AndroidBasicsExamples/tree/SAF)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it if its your file you created without permission, i know that. Heres code you can put this in a block and call it when needed. Also save each uri with str2 = uri.toString(); then shared preference string.

```
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(str2);
try{ DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri2);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
```